# CI DACPAC not deploying to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, dacpac

I am using DACPAC approach for my automatic database deployment on Azure Sql Server database from visual studio 2019,I have added DACPAC database for my local database now problem is that dacpac file is created in CI pipeline and going to release it on Azure SQL database using 'Azure SQL DacpacTask' but their I am facing issue while releasing the dacpac file.

```
*** Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ddltrg_CREATE_Activity_LOG, Line 16 Reference to database and/or server name in 'TrackDBChanges..tblDDLEventLog' is not supported in this v
ersion of SQL Server.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE TRIGGER [ddltrg_CREATE_Activity_LOG]
    ON DATABASE
    FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
    AS SET NOCOUNT ON;
       BEGIN
           DECLARE @xmlEventData AS XML;
           SET @xmlEventData = eventdata();
           IF CONVERT (VARCHAR (250), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)')) NOT IN ('model')
               INSERT INTO TrackDBChanges..tblDDLEventLog (EventTime, EventType, ServerName, DatabaseName, ObjectType, ObjectName, UserName, CommandText, CommandTextXML, HostName, LoginName)
               SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)')), 'T', ' '),
                      CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)')),
                      CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)')),
                      CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @xmlEventData.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)')),
                      CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @xmlEventDa
1 more errors. Click on expand view in the context menu to view complete logs.
```

[image]

my structure of Dacpac project
[image]

Comment: i am also facing the same issue since from last 2 days

Comment: Do you mind update your task definition here? The message code look like more relevant with the arguments you passed to the `sqlpackage.exe`. In addition, is it succeed for you to do this deploy by using `sqlpackage.exe` command?